# SQL Server : autoincrement fields separately

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns, where none of the columns is unique. I need to auto increment the column `number` separately for each user.

```
user | number
1    | 1
2    | 1
1    | 2 
3    | 1
```

The only idea I could come up with is to search for the last number used and manually increment by one. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You could write a function that calculates the auto-increment and make [number] a computed column that calls the function.

Comment: Create a separate table that holds the number per user which is better at least if your current table has a lot more rows than users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `number` field, You can create an `auto increment` field in the table (I call it `id`), and get the desired `number` via a query:

first adding id:

```
alter table table_name add id int not null IDENTITY(1,1)
```

you do not need the number field anymore:

```
alter table table_name drop column number
```

The query to get `number` (you can use it to create a view):

```
select user,
row_number() over(partition by user order by id) as number
from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for a user maximum and increment it.

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (user, number) 
SELECT (MAX(number) + 1)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE user = USER_ID
```

The term of auto-increment covers only the **primary key** auto-increment. See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp), for more information.

Comment: `only the primary key` I wouldn't be so sure. I can have non PK column with auto incremented values

Comment: The OP has already observed that this is an option, and is looking for others.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like in two query:

userno - id of user in integer you want to insert

first write(query 1) i.e if userno already there in table:

```
insert into table_name 
select userno,count(*) from table_name where user = userno 
group by user;
```

if it returns empty row then simply write(query 2) i.e it is a new user to be inserted:

```
insert into table_name values(userno,1);
```